# DJANGO how to send one of the model parameters instead of it's url to .json

Tags: python, json, django

I am a Django beginner and I believe this is a rather simple question, still, i couldn't find anything on it. Thanks in advance!

I am trying to get the parameter "nome" from the "Especie" model to appear on the .json file:

My models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Zona(models.Model):
    codigo      = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    especies    = models.ForeignKey('Especie')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.codigo


class Especie(models.Model):
    nome       = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    zonas      = models.ForeignKey(Zona)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome
```

My serialisers.py(using django rest framework):

```
class EspecieSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Especie
        fields = ('nome', 'nome_latino', 'zonas', 'id')
class ZonaSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Zona
        fields = ('codigo', 'area', 'especies', 'id')
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from species.models import Especie, Zona
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest.serializers import ZonaSerializer, EspecieSerializer

class EspecieViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = Especie.objects.all().order_by('-data_insercao')
    serializer_class = EspecieSerializer

class ZonaViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows groups to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = Zona.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ZonaSerializer
```

Instead im getting the URL to the "especie" in question, as you can see here:

```
"codigo": "A1",
        "area": "Alvalade",
        "especies": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/especies/1/",
        "id": 1
```

thank you!

Comment: Please show us the code that generates the output!

Comment: @klaus-d you're right, thx